# how get Count of array inside other array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the count of second array by `count()` metod ,
if Apply count method to external array i got 2,
  But ie `count($get_comment)`,i want internal array count ,
outer array has count 2

```
array (size=2)   0 => 
     array (size=2)
       0 => 
         object(stdClass)[12]
          public 'comment_ID' => string '23' (length=2)
        public 'comment_post_ID' => string '22' (length=2)
          public 'comment_author_IP' => string '::1' (length=3)

       1 => 
         object(stdClass)[13]
          public 'comment_ID' => string '20' (length=2)
          public 'comment_post_ID' => string '22' (length=2)
          public 'comment_author_IP' => string '::1' (length=3)

  1 => 
     array (size=2)
       0 => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
           public 'comment_ID' => string '22' (length=2)
           public 'comment_post_ID' => string '23' (length=2)
           public 'comment_author_IP' => string '::1' (length=3)


      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[15]
          public 'comment_ID' => string '21' (length=2)
          public 'comment_post_ID' => string '23' (length=2)
          public 'comment_author_IP' => string '::1' (length=3)
```

Comment: Show your code,with your output array ,whichu you want to count.

Comment: i want to get count of internal array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along theese lines should work

```
foreach($array as $key -> $getComment){
 echo count($getComment);
}
```

This loops over the parent array where $array is the outer level, and echo's the count of each item inside the array (The internal array).

If you want to save this count somewhere you could push the count onto another array.

```
$arrayCounter = array();
foreach($array as $key -> $getComment){
   $arrayCounter[] = count($getComment);
}
```